# Make dynamic arrays for each line of blocks from a file

Tags: c, file, dynamic-arrays

For example, we have 3 blocks, 4 lines each, the blocks in the file are separated by a new line.
I need to make 2D arrays for each row in the block, i.e. the first array for each first row of the blocks, the second array for each 2 row in the blocks, etc.

I made a function where I allocated memory for 2D arrays of strings, while the 3rd string has a float value, so I made a 1D array for it, then I try to get the values ​​from the file and fill arrays with them.
When I run the function, it doesn't work, and I don't understand what exactly is the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN_STR1 11
#define LEN_STR2 4
#define LEN_STR3 3
#define numberOfBlocks 3

int dynamic_arrays(FILE** file, char **string1, char **string2, char **string3, float *string4)
{
    *file = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    if ( *file == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Error opening the file\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {   //making 2D arrays
        string1 = (char**)malloc(numberOfBlocks * sizeof(char));
        string2 = (char**)malloc(numberOfBlocks * sizeof(char));
        string3 = (char**)malloc(numberOfBlocks * sizeof(char));
        string4 = (float*)malloc(numberOfBlocks * sizeof(float));
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBlocks; i++)
        {
            string1[i]=(char*)malloc(LEN_STR1*sizeof(char));
            string2[i] = (char*)malloc(LEN_STR2*sizeof(char));
            string3[i] = (char*)malloc(LEN_STR3*sizeof(char));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBlocks; i++)
        {
            if(fscanf(*file, "%s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n", string1[i], string2[i], string3[i], string4[i]) != EOF)
            {
                printf("%s\n", string1[i]);
                printf("%s\n", string2[i]);
                printf("%s\n", string3[i]);
                printf("%s\n", string4[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(*file);
}

int main()
{
    FILE*file;
    char **string1;
    char **string2;
    char **string3;
    float *string4;


    dynamic_arrays(&file, string1, string2, string3, string4);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBlocks; i++)
    {
    free(string1[i]);
    free(string2[i]);
    free(string3[i]);
    }
    free(string1);
    free(string2);
    free(string3);
    free(string4);

    return 0;
}
```

And file example. In file we in the file, we know in advance the length of each line except 4.

```
9458133410
A11
R2
5.254453

9458133410
Z13
R2
50.254254

9458133410
Z11
R1
5.254254
```

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_ - Please describe the details about that. How did you come to that conclusion? If you are using `gcc` or `clang` compile with `-Wall -Wextra` to get some hints about problems. You need to fix them all. In `gcc` you can also add `-fanalyzer` to get even more in-depth information.

Comment: In C arguments are passed *by value*. That means the value used in the call is *copied* into the functions local argument variable. Assignments or other changes to the functions local argument variables will only happen to those variables. The original value use in the call will not change. You seem to remember that for the `file` argument (which you don't need to pass *at all*) but not for the string arrays.

Comment: On another note, you should probably spend some time to learn about *structures*, because then you don't really need to pass arguments at all, just create an array of the structure (dynamically allocated), and *return* it from the function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know about structures, but I'm not allowed to use them in this task:(